# How to handle different color schemes in large projects

Tags: css, sass, themes

I've been searching all day to find a way to implement different color themes. Most solutions implement this on a small scale (change the body background and text for instance). But what I've a large project that has different types of cards, buttons, forms, etc. Something like this won't be enough of course:

```
:root {
    --body-text-clr: #232323;
    --body-bg-clr: #fff;
}
:root[data-theme="dark"] {
    --body-text-clr: #fff;
    --body-bg-clr: #232323;
}
```

Usually, I have **a lot of** colors like this:

```
:root {

    // THOSE USUALLY DON'T CHANGE
    --clr-primary-400: somevalue;
    --clr-primary-500: somevalue;
    --clr-primary-600: somevalue;

    // THOSE CHANGE COMPLETELY
    --clr-neutral-100: somevalue;
    --clr-neutral-200: somevalue;
    --clr-neutral-300: somevalue;
    --clr-neutral-400: somevalue;
    --clr-neutral-500: somevalue;
    --clr-neutral-600: somevalue;
}
```

and every color is used multiple times in different places. I tried to solve this in different ways but none worked. Here's some of the methods I tried to implement:

#### Method 1: Leave it as it is

I thought the design was made in a way that every color in the light mode corresponds to another color in the dark mode. But it didn't take me long until I realized this is not the case. Some elements have a shared background in a particular theme but they don't share the same background in another theme.

#### Method 2: Tokens

I tried to do something like this:

```
// I DO THIS FOR EVERY COMPONENT I HAVE
:root {
    --card-text-clr: somevalue;
    --card-bg-clr: somevalue;
}

:root[data-theme="dark"] {
    --card-text-clr: somevalue;
    --card-bg-clr: somevalue;
}
```

I don't have a problem that it's a lot of work to set that up. But my problem was that I couldn't use any utility classes to set my colors anymore (I won't generate a utility class for a single use like this `.card-bg` or `.card-text-clr`). If I want to set the background of my card, I'd have to do it in my CSS file.

I'm looking forwards to see how you approach this problem in your projects.
I don't have a problem if your solution includes using SASS since I use it already.

Answer (score 0):

1st option: assign the relevant theme class or attr to the body. and write CSS for each component according to the relevant theme class.

2nd option: create the color palette using variables and change the variables. color palette and variable should be designed or planned first on the design side / figma.
for example: https://github.com/royalfig/dark-mode-demo/blob/master/main.scss

```
       &[color-mode="light"] {
      --surface1: #e6e6e6;
      --surface2: #f2f2f2;
      --surface3: #ffffff;
      --element1: #111111;
      --element2: #222222;
      --element3: #333333;
      --elementInverse: #eee;
      --primary: #01408e;
      --secondary: #3c5d5c;
      --tertiary: #fff7d6;
      --box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px #cacaca, -20px -20px 60px #ffffff;
    }

    &[color-mode="dark"] {
      --surface1: #262626;
      --surface2: #333333;
      --surface3: #404040;
      --element1: #eeeeee;
      --element2: #dddddd;
      --element3: #cccccc;
      --elementInverse: #111;
      --primary: #8fceff;
      --secondary: #72faca;
      --tertiary: #eee8a9;
      --box-shadow: 20px 20px 60px #1d1d1d, -20px -20px 60px #272727;
    }
    }
```

You can use whichever is simpler.

Comment: But the the second option is just what I call as _tokens_. I find this approach great but the only problem is that anything related to colors should be set in the CSS file (I can't use utility classes with this).

Comment: why you cant use utility classes with this?
if you mean color-mode=dark classes. you can use normal class like class="red-theme". its have to be in css file. also you can use javascript for switch class to body.

Comment: This is not what I mean. If I don't have tokens, I could do something like this: `<div class="bg-neutral-500">SOME CONTENT</div>`. But I can't do this when I have variables like `surface1` and `element` as I don't have utility classes for them, and it would be tedious to generate a utility class that is used in one single place

Comment: Let's assume there are 3 different themes.
When you type class=theme1 in body. All css will change accordingly.
Same way for theme2 and theme 3.

You do not need to write a class other than the body, you just need to write special css for the body class for each component.

If this is not the solution, unfortunately I could not understand you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using `tailwindcss` so you should look at [daisyui themes](https://daisyui.com/docs/themes/).

Alternatively, This is what i do which is influenced by materializecss.

```
/// Select five colors for the theme. 
/// Two lights
/// Mid
/// Two Darks
$theme-colors: (
    "lightest":  #FFFFFF,
    "light":  #D3D3DD,
    "bright":     #DEC2B5,
    "dark": #32422b,
    "darkest": #000000,    
);

$all-themes: lightest1, lightest2, light1, light2, bright1, bright2, dark1, dark2, darkest1, darkest2;

@function themecolor($color) {
    @if map-has-key($theme-colors, $color) {
        @return map-get($theme-colors, $color);
    }
    @warn "Unknown `#{$color}` in $style-colors.";
    @return null;
}

.lightest1 {
    color: themecolor("darkest");
    background: themecolor("lightest");
}
.lightest2 {
    color: themecolor("dark");
    background: themecolor("lightest");
}

.light1 {
    color: themecolor("darkest");
    background: themecolor("light");
}
.light2 {
    color: themecolor("dark");
    background: themecolor("light");
}

.bright1 {
    color: themecolor("bright");
    background: themecolor("darkest");
}

.bright2 {
    color: themecolor("darkest");
    background: themecolor("bright");
}

.dark1 {
    color: themecolor("light");
    background: themecolor("dark");
}
.dark2 {
    color: themecolor("bright");
    background: themecolor("dark");
}
.darkest1 {
    color: themecolor("lightest");
    background: themecolor("darkest");
}
.darkest2 {
    color: themecolor("light");
    background: themecolor("darkest");
}
```

And then for particular widgets such as buttons.

```
 .lightest1 .btn-themed {
    outline: 2px solid themecolor("darkest");
    color: themecolor("darkest");
    background: themecolor("lightest");
  }
.lightest1 .btn-themed:hover {
    color: themecolor("lightest");
    background: themecolor("darkest");
}
```